# replaceText Google Apps Script pass through blank values to Google Doc Merge

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm doing something like a mail merge - taking values from google sheets (actually script array) and replacing placeholder variables in a google doc template. I have about 50 of these. Below are three of them. The format looks like this:

```
body.replaceText("{Property Address}", propertyAddress);
body.replaceText("{Lead Type}", leadType);
body.replaceText("{Deal Type}", dealType);
```

The problem I'm running into is sometimes a variable can be blank - e.g. say `leadType` is blank or `""`. There is an error occurring if it's blank. What I want to do is if `leadType` has a value, then replace `{Lead Type}` in the Google Doc with the value. Else if `leadType` = `null` or `""` or `undefined` etc., then replace `{Lead Type}` in the Google Doc with `""`. I'd rather not have to do an if/then statement for each of these 50 lines. Is there an easy way to have either a value or a blank push through to the sheet (I want a blank to go through because I don't want the final sheet to be printed with {} variables)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `leadType = null or "" or undefined etc.` and `a value or a blank push through to the sheet`. In your script, for example, how about using the logical "OR" operator like `body.replaceText("{Lead Type}", leadType || "");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the OR operator?

```
body.replaceText("{Property Address}", propertyAddress || "");
body.replaceText("{Lead Type}", leadType || "");
body.replaceText("{Deal Type}", dealType || "");
```